# Can you buy Aluminum Nitride transistors?

Tags: transistors, semiconductors, materials

We all know wide bandgap semiconductors, currently galium nitride and silicon carbide are the superstars becose many companies make them at relatively reasonable price. They aren't just mere lab curiosities but very real choices.

There are also many more wide bandgap semiconductor materials with even higher bandgaps such as diamond, silicon nitride, boron nitride, silicon dioxide and aluminum nitride a.k.a. AlN.

I read on wikipedia that military uses AlN transistors, which means they are actively produced somewhere. Do you know any manufacturer that makes AlN transistors? I want to know if there is currently any commercialy avaliable AlN transistor.

Last thing I want to add to prevent potential mistake, aluminum nitride have also high thermal conductivity, it’s a frequent substitude for toxic beryllium oxide used in transistor as heat spreader thermal material. I am looking for transistor that uses it as semiconductor, not as heatsink.

Comment: I apologise if this seems obvious or unhelpful. First, please include a link to the page that says the military is using AlN transistors, to help people who may read your question in future. Second, most companies who are selling technology make an effort to publish information about their products on the www. So I would expect to be able to use a web search engine to find Aluminum Nitride transistors if they are available commercially. What did you find? Are you hoping that someone on this forum will have 'inside information'?

Comment: wiki doesn't say the military use AIN transistors... it says "military applications," NOTHING about them using it as a semiconductor. Where have you seen transistors. AIN is used in alot of places

Comment: JohnRB I assumed they use it as semiconductor material for some kind microwave transistor like in radar phase array.

Comment: Please post the link to the page that you read which caused you to believe that AlN transistors are in production and being used by the military. As it is, you are asking people to spend their time trying to find the same information as you already have. Otherwise this reads like _'I think the military are using AlN transistors, but there is no evidence that they are, and no one is claiming to make AlN transistors'_. In that case it is probably not answerable within the terms of this site, and hence will likely get closed.

Comment: gbulmer From Wikipedia,wide bandgap semiconductor page,under HEMT "Due to its cost, aluminum nitride is so far used mostly in military applications"  This directly states military is using AlN HEMT transistors.

Comment: Those who manufacture and use AIN transistors have no obligation to state that they do. Often cutting-edge technology is kept in the black for some time. When it is in widespread use then restrictions are rolled back. No AIN for ISIS.

Comment: I just realized one thing,what we call Galium Nitride transistors arent only from Galium Nitride,they can also contain Aluminum Galium Nitride or even  pure Aluminum Nitride in certain part/layer https://3c1703fe8d.site.internapcdn.net/newman/gfx/news/hires/2009/20090624-01cl.jpg       So when that person who wrote the Wiki page,he probably meant its used as layer in Galium Nitride HEMT transistors for military radar,not as the primary semiconductor with 6 eV bandgap.